# Unity FPS Game Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am getting an error in this script.

> UnityEngine does not contain a definition for rigidbody (Lines: 22,24)

```
public class GunShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject BulletPrefab;
    public float BulletSpeed;
    public int BulletsInClip;
    public AudioClip GunshotSound;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot")){
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot() {
        var bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation);
        bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * BulletSpeed);
        audio.PlayOneShot(GunshotSound);
        BulletsInClip--;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what to edit instead of just editing the script.

Comment: Are you asking if you're getting error in this script? Also, if an error tells you that some type doesn't contain a definition for rigid body, it means it doesn't contain a definition for rigid body.

Comment: It is what it says. The `bullet` object's type doesn't contain a member with the name `rigidbody`.

Comment: it has a rigid body component on it though??

Comment: @Polynomial Please elaborate what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to [Instantiate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) doesn't result in a [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html). It will return a plain [Object](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.html). So subsequently you're trying to access the RigidBody - using `bullet.rigidbody` -  which an Object has no knowledge about.

When instantiating therefore perform an explicit cast:

```
var bullet = (GameObject) Instantiate(BulletPrefab, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation);
```

Or even explicitly write `GameObject bullet = ...` to avoid errors like this. If you do, the compiler will start to complain at the location of the true error if you forget the cast.

Comment: `GameObject bullet = ...` will still result in a compiler error without the cast..

Comment: Yes @Joe, but the point being that the error will be more clear. I made that more clear (I hope). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah, much clearer now. Thanks for updating